# MySQL Advanced Ordering combining two queries

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-order-by

I'm getting the following data using two queries which I'm then using a `UNION ALL` to combine:

[image: InitialData]

- First part: All `IN` events are sorted using SideA then EventTime
- Second part: All `OUT` events are sorted the same way

However, I'd like the final result to be as follows:

- Insert the `OUT` events in the corresponding EventTime where `out.SideB=in.SideA`
- You'll notice that for each OUT event there's a correspodning IN event but sometimes it's not the case (case highlighted in orange).
- Also the timings might not be identical 100% so it can't be used for matching.

So the final result should be like this:

[image: endResults]

Please advise how to proceed.

**PS:** Please find the data used in my example in this [GoogleSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jvNElmlAwyOBYhGT6kKT9quQ9vn58zyoGA3pnNVEbPQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am thinking of an `order by` clause like:

```
order by 

    -- if event type is 1, order by SideA, else order by SideB        
    case when EventType = 'IN' then SideA else SideB end,

    -- then event time
    EventTime,

    -- `Out` goes before `IN` if there are several events at the same time
    EventType desc
```

Comment: Man, that is perfect. I've seen similar solutions but I couldn't reproduce one since I didn't understand how it works. Would you please add a detailed explanation if possible so the anwser will help better in other situations.

Comment: @Enissay: welcome! This is conditional ordering, I added more information to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I've used it before in a simple way, but this combination confused me. Thank you for the extra explanations.